# With Rails, how to sudo ./runner despite a minimal sudo PATH and gem not being in /usr/bin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sudo

My context:

- ruby-enterprise 1.8.7, on a CentOS 5
- ruby and gem are installed in /usr/local/bin
- ./runner: runs correctly
- sudo ./runner

  > Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2. Please install RubyGems and try again: http://rubygems.rubyforge.org

  (because sudo has a limited PATH)
- sudo PATH=$PATH ./runner: runs correctly, as runner has /usr/local/bin in its PATH again

Question:

Are there other alternatives (possibly more elegant - with minimal changes) to launch runner with sudo, when gem is not in /bin or /usr/bin ?

Those I would think of (but not satisfied with):

- putting a symlink to gem in /usr/bin
- modifying runner ?
- modifying sudoers ?

Maybe there is a way with a config file or a command line argument to runner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `env_file` option in `sudoers` and put your path specification in a file that it points to. Something like:

**`sudoers`:**

```
Cmnd_Alias    RUBY = /path/to/runner
Defaults!RUBY env_file=/path/to/rubypathfile
ALL ALL=(ALL) RUBY
```

**`/path/to/rubypathfile`:**

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

You may also find the `env_keep` option useful.

Take a look at `sudo sudo -V | less` and see if it tells you anything of interest. Particularly do a case-insensitive search for "path" or "ruby".

Comment: Thanks Dennis, especially for the `sudo sudo -V` tip.